# ADO.net BETWEEN Weird Behavior

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, ado.net

I'm not sure whts wrong with this code...

```
else if (combo_View.Text == "Orders")
{

    da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TestQuery WHERE (VendorName = @VendorName OR @VendorName = '') AND (CustomerName = @CustomerName OR @CustomerName = '') AND (PO = @PO OR @PO = '')  AND (ItemNum = @ItemNum OR @ItemNum = '') AND (orderDate BETWEEN @From AND @To) ORDER BY CustomerName", cs);

    //da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TestQuery WHERE orderDate BETWEEN @From AND @To", cs);

    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@VendorName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = combo_VendorView.Text.ToString();
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = combo_CustomerView.Text.ToString();

    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@From", OleDbType.Date).Value = "#" + tp_viewFrom.Value.Date.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + "#";
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@To", OleDbType.Date).Value = "#" + tp_viewTo.Value.Date.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + "#";

    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@PO", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_POLookup.Text.ToString();
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ItemNum", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = combo_ItemNumLookup.Text.ToString();


    dsB.Clear();
    da.Fill(dsB);
    dgv_DataLookup.DataSource = dsB.Tables[0];
}
```

basiclly, I want to fill a datagrid with a between statement. For the uncommented SelectCommand, I appear to get no values on my datagrid when a select valid dates. However, when I take out the comments of the select command after that, it works when its only date. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with the first command when I have other parameters with it? Thanks

Edit:

More strangeness, when I use this select command:

```
da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TestQuery WHERE
    (VendorName = @VendorName OR @VendorName = '')
    AND (CustomerName = @CustomerName OR @CustomerName = '')
    AND orderDate BETWEEN @From AND @To ORDER BY CustomerName", cs);
```

it works but I add anything more to it and it stops...

Comment: Did you check the message text in Query Analizer? Can you provide it?

Comment: Can you run that query directly on the database and get results?

Comment: Read this blog post on [Catch-all queries](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/).

Comment: So probably your PO and ItemNum columns are numeric.

Comment: PO and ItemNum columns are varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any of your data values or the parameters themselves in the between clause are null, the between will always be false.  Test for null values on the @from and @to and put the between in an or with that test.

```
and (@from is null or @to is null or <between stmt> )
```

Comment: not the exact answer I had to add a few things but was close enough. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is you date select that is the problem. I think it is some of the statements like this one:

```
VendorName = @VendorName OR @VendorName = ''
```

Do you really mean `@VendorName = ''` or did you mean to write `VendorName = ''`?

My suspicion is that since you are AND'ing all the clauses together in your `WHERE` that you are getting no data back because there is no data that meets all the criteria.

EDIT
Based on your further edit, it sounds like once you add more data that you are excluding/filtering by you get no results, so I would again suggest that there are no results because no data fits that tightened criteria.

Comment: No I think his logic is correct, it looks like he means "if the param has a value compare it to a field, if it has no value then evaluate to true", only applying filtering if the user has supplied a vlue for that field.

Comment: this is what i thought at first but before this, if i take the date out everything worked...

Comment: Okay, yeah, that makes sense now that I think about it. I would probably have restructered this personally so that I would not even generate the WHERE clause for values that were not supplied, using a `StringBuilder` to hold the query as I built it up.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost certainly caused by the values being passed into the other parameters are causing one or more of your other clauses to evaluate to false.  Check what is being put into the non date params in a debugger and/or profile the database to pull out the values..

Comment: Hi, so this is what I tried. I took out the Between clause and everything worked just fine (put in vendor, customer name but no PO or ItemName). I'm pretty sure i covered the dates that actually had orders too.